# packaging Java library with dependencies in OSGi/Eclipse jars

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, software-packaging

I am finishing a Java library that I want to make available to third parties. 
In addition to its core functionality, I am providing some classes that ease the usage of my library when used as part of an Eclipse plugin.
Then, I have some dependencies in my library to certain OSGi/Eclipse classes (e.g., `org.osgi.framework.Bundle`, `org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator`, `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit`, among others).

So my questions is: What is the correct/convenient way to package this library for third parties usage?. Should I include all the Eclipse jars that contain the required dependencies ?. Intuitively, I think this is not a good solution given that the user obviously could have a different Eclipse version than the one I have, and this could lead to class loading conflicts. The solution of just not providing the Eclipse jars - and asking the user to find the ones he/she likes - does not really convince me neither.

I do not have lots of experience with Maven, but as far as I understand I can create a POM file that the user can use for downloading the last version of my project and its dependencies. But again: in that case I also have to decide if I should include or not the Eclipse jars in the download, considering the reasons I wrote above.

Thanks for sharing your experience on this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Installation and updates are managed in Eclipse using a provisioning platform called [p2](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_overview.htm).

The most convenient way is to create a [Feature](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/feature.htm) to package your plugins/libraries and use [Feature Export wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_features.htm) to create p2 meta-data repository from where your feature can be installed. P2 will take care of the dependencies.